# Updating a Ansible role which has been installed with ansible-galaxy from a GitHub repo

Tags: github, ansible, roles, ansible-galaxy

Whenever I change code in my Ansible role in a repository, I also want to have that code updated in the roles directory on my test machine.
What I do to obtain the new code is to

1. remove the role by running `ansible-galaxy remove rolename`
2. install the role again by using `ansible-galaxy install git+https://url/rolename`

If I do not use the **remove** option before the **install**, ansible-galaxy just skips the role as it's already installed. It does not see the changed files in the repo as such.

What is the best way to achive this?

Answer (score 6):

It seems like the recommended path to update a role is to use the `--force` option.

From `ansible-galaxy install --help`

```
  -f, --force           Force overwriting an existing role or collection
```

For reference, also see those likes in their repository:

- https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/6466
- https://github.com/ansible/proposals/issues/23

So in your case

```sh
ansible-galaxy install --force git+https://url/rolename
```

Comment: This is utterly ridiculous considering the most fundamental principle of Ansible is idempotency. What were they thinking...